# VBA won't compile? "Error Accessing the system Registry"

Tags: vba, ms-access

I was working on a Form and then Access crashed. When I tried to open it, I was prompted with an error which I didn't recognize how to fix right away. Something like

> Form1 doesn't exist , if the invalid form name is in a macro ...

At the time, I couldn't figure it out, so I hit "Compact and Repair", closed and re-opened access a few times. Then there was another message, don't exactly remember but soemhting like "To continue, all VBA code must be deleted."  I said Ok, because I have a few back up copies.  But that didn't fix anything.

Then I figured out how to fix the original error.  "Form1" was my default form to open on startup, so I changed it. So everything works, I copy the code back in, but obviously the code doesn't work. The error message is:

> Compile Error user defined type

on the DAO.QueryDef

Then I follow MS Help and check the references, and when I click on Tools -> References, I get

> Error acessing the System Registry.

So, any thoughts that include not messsing with the Registry?

Comment: Your mdb seems corrupted. Create a new mdb, and import everything from the old one. And make daily backups !

Comment: I tried to open References in the Northwind database, and that gave the same "error acessing registry."
I just tried it on another computer. It COULD open references but still gives a "user defined" error.

Comment: Did you try compact/repair?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so the real problem was the

> Compile Error: User-Defined Type Not Defined

iDevelop was right, the file was corrupted. I had to make a new access file (they were .accdb not .mbd , but some concept), and import all objects without the code.

To make sure wasn't corrupted, I copy pasted it into Notepad first, and then into the new file. (Just as an extra precaution).  And then it worked.

I am still getting the error:

> Error accessing the System Registry.

when I go into Tools-> references,

but, I think it is probably related to my permissions, so maybe it is intended.

Comment: For the references error message: try to Repair your Access setup ?